# Ionic httpClient response use toast

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, toast

i send login data to service, after get response in *login.ts* toast is not difined, how to resolve this ?

*i try my toast function in another function withot condition in service its work*

> this my function for load service **login.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, MenuController, PopoverController } from "ionic-angular";
import { TabsInfluencerComponent } from '../../influencer/tabs/tabs';
import { RegisterComponent } from '../register/register';
import { ResetComponent } from '../reset/reset';
import { OfferComponent } from '../../advertiser/offer/offer';
import { ngForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '../../../services/auth';
import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';



@Component({
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html',

})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        public nav:NavController, 
        public menu:MenuController, 
        public popover: PopoverController, 
        private AuthService : AuthService, 
        private toastCtrl: ToastController) {

    }   

    responseData : any;
    public isChoose: boolean = false;
    public isshowP: boolean = false;
    //login and get data in service
    login(form: ngForm){
        this.AuthService.login(form.value.email, form.value.password)
        .then(function(data) {
            if(data.success == true){
                localStorage.setItem('userToken',data.token);
                localStorage.setItem('userData',JSON.stringify(data.user));
            }else{
                let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                  message: data.error,
                  duration: 3000
                });
                toast.present();
            }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }


}
```

> this my service **auth.ts**:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'


@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    private loginUrl : string = 'http://localhost:8000/api/login';
    data : any;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient){}
    //function for login
    login(email : string, password :string){
        const body = {email : email, password : password};
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          this.http.post(this.loginUrl, body)
            .subscribe(data => {
              this.data = data;
              resolve(this.data);
            });
        });
    }

    register(email : string, password :string){

    }
}
```

after run i have error like this :
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'toastCtrl' of undefined**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it is a problem with your `this` reference in your **login.ts**.

```
.then(function(data) {
    ...
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
        message: data.error,
        duration: 3000
    });
    ...
})
```

The `this` is referring the anonymous function in your `then` block, but you want to refer back to your `LoginComponent` class.

**How to solve this?**

You could use arrow functions, that are really popular right now.

```
.then((data) => {
    ...
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
        message: data.error,
        duration: 3000
    });
    ...
})
```